# This PATH Variable is apparently invalid, not sure how to remedy it

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, path

In the process of fixing my Java PATH variables for development, I was recommended this Windows app called Rapid Environment Editor, which seems to be pretty dope indeed. I was able to fix my invalid Java variables, and fix my compiling issue, but during that process I found another variable to be invalid. By invalid, I mean the path doesn't exist in my file system.

C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Above is the path in question. Upon investigating, the only WindowsApps folder I have found is on my E:\ drive, where I keep all my secondary programs and mass storage files (i.e. videos, pics, etc.).

Should I change the path variable to point to this location? Or is that not the correct solution?

Comment: *the only WindowsApps folder I have found, is on my E:\ drive* WindowsApps is hidden subfolder in ProgramFiles folder.

Comment: “should I change the path variable to point to this location?” - No; The path is correct, you don’t actually have a problem, that needs to be solved

Comment: what do you mean ? Then why is it pointing to an invalid/non-existing location on the filesystem ? If I don't need it, then wouldn't it be best to remove said variable so that I have one less thing cluttering my PATH. Because from what I've always been taught since I was a wee computer geek, was too many variables in your path, can clutter it, which is No Bueno.

Comment: Doesn't exist, or just that you can't see it?